# Design pattern for applying a set functions based on the type of data entity

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

Example:
I have different types of employees in office:

- Software engineers
- HR
- Sales
- Marketing

I need to do a bunch of operations on the data of employees:

- Assess year-end performance and give a rating
- Based on rating, calculate performance bonus
- Based on rating, calculate salary hike percentage
- Issue bonus in next pay
- Update salary based on hike percentage
- Send out emails about rating, performance bonus and hike to employees

Problem:

- The operations mentioned above will differ from the type of employee it is operating on(e.g. calculate performance rating for s/w engineer will be different compared to that of marketing person).
- Some operations can be same while same may be enhancement to other operations(e.g. update salary based on hike percentage for software engineer will be same as that for sales person).
- In future there can be addition of new set of employees and a new set of operations need to be written.

My Approach:

- I have a driver class which has a list of operations and the employeeData.
- A method in Driver called executeOperations calls the operations in the list one by one on the data.
- The driver class will be initialised to an object by my main class depending on the type of employee data I am dealing with and the object will contain list of operations relevant to the type of employee data selected from a repository of functions.

What should be a good way to tackle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since your algorithm will change depending on the type of object, you can use [Strategy Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm).

You can change the calculations and algorithm based on the employee type.